# Simple Concurrency ASP.NET Database

Tags: asp.net, database, concurrency

Suppose that I have a bank account table with columns customer_id, name, address, and balance. Balance is constantly changing because customer is depositing and withdrawing money. How can I chance customer's address without getting an DBConcurrencyException at the same time?

What is the general approach in this situation, it is not possible for two users to change the SAME cell in a table row but it is possible for them to change different cells in same row AND updating the row with new values without problem?

Comment: I hope this isn't for a real bank. If you're actually storing `name`, `address` and `balance` in the same table, you're already doing it wrong! Read up on Normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at link http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/18/sql-server-detailed-explanation-of-transaction-lock-lock-type-avoid-locks/ which has detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using LINQ, but if you are then you should take a look at how it handles concurrency. LINQ uses optimistic concurrency. So basically if a a user attempts to update a record, and the record has been updated in the interim, then a concurrency conflict occurs.

However, you can decide which properties in your LINQ table are used for concurrency checking-- in which case LINQ won't care if the value in that record was changed.

There are also ways to handle the exception- you could put a try block around the exception-- and write some code to handle different scenarios.